# PHP functionality ($_[value]) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have been trying to get a php code to work through an ajax call but it doesnt seem to work (even though its posting and etc) when im simply assigning a value. I know the php code works when I just put it directly on the page but I want this to load after a button is pressed. My question is what would be the javascript equalivant to doing:

```
$_['dog'] = 'red';
```

Update:

the value 'dog' is already a value , the php code is simply changing it to 'red'  for clarification. And the ajax call since I just wanted the code to be run this was my call :

```
function ajaxPost() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      console.log("success");
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "https://linkto.com/lan.php", false);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send();
}
ajaxPost();
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  That PHP code, assuming `$_` is an array, adds a key `dog` with the value `red`.

Comment: Simply `_['dog'] = 'red';` if the array is not defined you can define with `let _ = []`. Btw `_` is not a meaningful name so better use another name ;)

Comment: What is the code for your AJAX call?  Do you have your PHP code print out any data (possibly via `json_encode`)?  What do you mean by "directly on the page?"

Comment: JavaScript and PHP are 2 different languages and they don't "talk" to each other.  PHP code runs on the server and it generates HTML/JavaScript code that the browser runs.  When you make an AJAX call, it makes a request to your server where the PHP runs.  That code should print something (like maybe JSON data) then the browser sees that printed data as the result from the AJAX call.  Then JavaScript can parse/process that data.

Comment: @TeslaPill What does `console.log(response);` show?  What is `lan.php?status=disp` doing?  What problem are you trying to solve?  I still don't know what the question here is.

Comment: console.log shows nothing, the status=disp I am using because I saw it in an example. All im trying to do is change the variable 'dog' to a different value. Which is changed by the php code I have. But because its server code it does it right away instead of waiting for a button so my question was to convert this into javascript so I can do it after a button press. The ajax call was not changing it .

Comment: Is `dog` a PHP variable?  Where is its value stored?  When your page is shown in the browser, the PHP code is *finished* running and all its memory is cleared.  So, when your AJAX call is run, PHP is spun up again, the code on the server runs, and then PHP exits and clears its memory.  PHP and JavaScript are 2 different languages, PHP generates the HTML and then exits.  I think you may be confused on what PHP does.  You'll probably need to store this `dog` variable in a database or in a memcache so you can access its value after PHP exits.

Comment: Also, don't just copy code you saw in an example without understanding what it's doing.  `?status=disp` is a query parameter and is accessed in PHP via `$_GET['status']`.  If you are not using it in PHP, then you don't need to pass these query parameters.  Also, you should lookup a newer AJAX example in JavaScript, `new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")` hasn't been used in *years*.

Comment: i changed the ajax code and its updated , dog is a key stored on the page from a different function/file.It determines the color of the page on refresh. The value is the 'red' since its 'blue' on default.